# Getting value our of array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

quick question that Im sure is easy, but I cant find an answer.

When I run

```
print_r ($fields);
```

I get the output of

```
mFields Object ( [fields] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [linkId] => 260 [fieldType] => corename [caption] => Name [value] => Auto Title Loans in Los Angeles
```

What I need is to turn two of these elements into single php variables.
I need the [linkId] => 260 to be a variable, and the Name [value] to be a variable.

This would make $linkid="260"; and $linkname="Auto Title Loans in Los Angeles";

Can anyone please help me do this?
Thank you!
Jason

Comment: Sorry, but that's basic PHP syntax. You should learn it on your own: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. see example #6

Comment: Im looking at that now, having a hard time connecting how that array, and my array would out put the same, If I could get an example here, it would teach me how to do it from now on.

Comment: If you do `var_dump($fields);` instead of `print_r()` you will be able to understand the hierarchy of the object better. Give it a shot.

Comment: that gives me: object(mFields)#693 (4) { ["fields"]=> array(10) { [0]=> array(29) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["linkId"]=> int(398) ["fieldType"]=> string(8) "corename" ["caption"]=> string(4) "Name" ["value"]=> string(27) "Title Loans in Camarillo CA"

Comment: I suggest to surround print_r with html '<pre></pre>' tags - to keep line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

$linkid =   $fields->fields[0]['linkId'];
$linkname = $fields->fields[0]['value'];